Describe the entries of this heteroclinic sequence of numbers
I am working with an exercise in Devaney, which is about the following sequence
$(\mathbf{1})=(\dots11.111\dots) \in \Sigma_2$
A sequence $\mathbf{s}$ is said to be heteroclinic if $\mathbf{s}\in W^s(\textbf{0})\cap W^u(\textbf{1})$, where  $W^s$ and  $W^u$ are the stable and unstable subspaces of a sequence.
A stable subspace of a sequence, is that sequence of numbers that leads towards some periodic point, while the unstable subspace of a sequence is that sequence of numbers that leads away from a periodic point.
A sequence $\Sigma_2$ is an infinite sequence of $1$'s or $0$'s. So $(\mathbf{1})$ is an infinite sequence of $1$'s, while  $(\mathbf{0})$
is an infinite sequence of zeros.
I am not sure I understand this question right, "Describe the entries of such a heteroclinic sequence", and if that means to find the entries of the stable and unstable spaces of the sequence $\mathbf{1}$.
If that is the thing to do, how can I find that, when there is no clear periodic point here?
Thanks

Note that these "leads towards" and "leads away" are given by some distance in the one-sided version of $\Sigma_2$ (the specific distance is not too important since there are many equivalent ones, but you should use whatever your book specifies; note also that you cannot use a two-sided version of the distance).
To construct a heteroclinic sequence $s$ in $W^s(\textbf{0})\cap W^u(\textbf{1})$ you need a sequence that is $0$ after some position and that is $1$ before some other position, that is, it must have the form
$$
s=(\cdots11111\,\boxed{\rm arbitrary}\,00000\cdots).
$$
On the other hand, any such sequence is in $W^s(\textbf{0})\cap W^u(\textbf{1})$, which thus gives you a complete description of the heteroclinic sequences.

Ok, and the period of s remains 1, anyway and a periodic point is either 0 or 1?

We don't say that $s$ is periodic, although indeed both $00000\cdots$ and $\cdots11111$ are periodic of period $1$ (respectively, to the future and to the past). It is as if you project $\bf0$ and $\bf1$ to one-sided sequences (respectively, to the future and to the past).

One more thing, why was the question about the sequence $(\mathbf{1})$ and then we are considering both $(\mathbf{1})$ and $(\mathbf{0})$?

That's just how the book formulates the problem. But there is nothing special about $\bf1$ (or $\bf0$). In general you can consider any two periodic points $\bf p$ and $\bf q$, and describe the heteroclinic sequences in $W^s(\textbf{p})\cap W^u(\textbf{q})$ (which may be different from those in $W^s(\textbf{q})\cap W^u(\textbf{p})$).

Is that where we devise $$W^s(p)={z|F^n(z)-F^n(p)|\to0, \text{as}\ n\to\infty }$$ and
$$ W^u(p)={z|F^n(p)-F^n(z)|\to0 , \text{as}\ \to\infty } $$ ? Thanks

Precisely, using the one-sided distances here.

And in the given example you made, it would be $W^s(1)={z|F^n(z)-F^n(1)|$. But what is z?

$z$ is the sequence $s$.

Interesting, I have however not idea how that computation will look like..maybe that merits a separate question
